# JPA ManyToMany and mappedBY

Tags: jpa

I completely understand @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, and @ManyToMany. However the mappedBy = "some collection or class" has be confused.

From my understanding, the many part is always the owning side. For example,

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "company")
  public class CompanyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idcompany")
    private Integer idcompany;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<EmployeeEnity> employeeEnity
```

This is saying a company can have many employees. The one being the company and the Many being the employees.

However with @ManyToMany we still have a inverse side too. This is what I do not understand. @ManyToMany just means there is a table in the middle, so how do you determine the inverse and the owner?

I know mappedBy is mandatory, but choosing on where to put it is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bidirectional OneToMany, the many side MUST be the owner side.

For a ManyToMany, you have the choice: you decide which side is the owner side and which side is the inverse side.

Note that, in your example, either the association is unidirectional, and the unique side (the one side) is thus obviously the owner side, or the association is bidirectional, and the mapping is thus incorrect, since the one side MUST be the inverse side and should thus have a `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private Collection<EmployeeEntity> employees;
```

Comment: I have a choice yes, it is making this choice. For example: A company can have many Clients and a Client can have many companies. Who is unique?

Comment: Nobody is unique. Unicity doesn't have anything to do with your question. You can choose to make company the owner side, or client. You decide.